# How to get contact in xamarin forms app using pcl

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms PCL app, and I want to get contacts,
I saw this plugin
https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.Contacts
Because I am a new xamarin trainee I could not use it.
I need someone who explain to and train me how I use it.
I need that not for this exact plugin, I need that for another plugins which I will use them in my Journey with xamarin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms.Contacts can be installed via NuGet:

Here's a tutorial to install any nuget via visual studio (it's quite similar for mac as well):

https://dzone.com/articles/install-nuget-packages-in-visual-studio

You also have to add permission on both platforms, as stated in the project readme:

1. Android -> AndroidManifest.xml

add the following node: 
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

2. iOS -> info.plist

add the following node:

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need contact permission to do ...</string>
```

After that, you should be able to use it in your project without problems.

Comment: Thank you , mymistake was that I got the files from github and I was tring to use them inside my project without knowledge that I have to install plugin via NuGet. Thank you so much and Excuse my new relationship with Xamarin and NuGet.